# If a question is "what is the LanguageX equivalent of LanguageY's complex feature Z..." should both languages be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: while I agree the linked question appears to be a duplicate, this question is specifically about a situation where an equivalent of an above-average complexity statement or feature use is being sought. I think there's some merit to keeping the source language tagged if it helps attract developers who are well conversant in the source language (because they'll need to be to be able to work out what it's doing) as well as the target language..

I caught a pending edit that was essentially "How do I do this C# thing in Java?" and both Java and C# were tagged. The edit was to remove the C# tag, as strictly speaking it IS just a question for someone who knows Java, but this was related to C#'s LINQ, which can make for confusing reading at times and has a lot going on behind the scenes that really only a LINQ experienced C# dev would know... So I didn't see it as strictly a Java-only question due to (IMHO) the level of C# that was required.

Is there a general rule, that only one of the languages should be tagged? Should both languages be tagged? Is it context dependent based on the complexity of the feature being discussed (if involved, like LINQ, tag both.. If simple, like for loop, struct declaration etc., have only the target language)?

Comment: I agree it seems related from the title, though it might not be an exact duplicate because that question has a well voted answer ("no, don't put both tags") that is pretty much the opposite of the best voted answer on this one ("yes put both")..

Comment: And it also makes the point - it's better if the question asker can *clearly describe* what (they think) feature Z actually *does* in Language Y. That way there are more potential answerers from the Language X pool (who may not know Y) or they may be able to offer solutions that are *nothing like* Z but Z happened to be the only way of achieving their aims in Language Y.

Answer (score 7):

I think that this kind of questions will probably be closed (unless they demonstrate the problem very well in both languages, and provide the solution attempts).

Given that the question was *not* closed, I think it's better to keep both tags, as this will attract users who are familiar with both languages, with better chances to know the solution, or to search for it. Also, we'll not be doing something wrong - the question indeed involves two languages.

Comment: *"attract users who are familiar with both languages"* - is wrong. You need an expert in `X`, who apparently knows enough of `Y` to be able to answer. An expert in `Y` will downvote and vote-close such question. And he is totally right. Only `X` should be a tag. If `X` expert can't help, just wait for another `X` expert, `Y` experts won't help you. Do not try to attract them.

Comment: @sinatr my bad - it **might attract**.

Comment: *"the question indeed involves two languages"* - but the answer isn't.

Comment: @sinatr I get that your logic seems to be "I need an expert in X who knows enough Y" but does that necessarily mean that people who are "an expert in Y who know enough X to write an answer" should be excluded from the "pool of people we're trying to attract to the question" ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, yes, normally they will add `X` as tag if they are *willing* to give answers like this. I *might* be wrong in my position here. Personally I don't see a big harm in including both tags by beginners, but I don't like answers on meta encouraging this. To me it only make sense to include 2 languages if answer need them both, e.g. containing solution with code in both languages.. In given case it's enough to just provide `X` snippets. So `X` tag.

Comment: Actually you don't need `Y` knowledge in such answer if you explain what `Y` code do. You don't even need `Y` code in the question. It's enough to know what it does. It feels wrong when someone asking question can't explain what `Y` do without `Y` code. Yes, it's *shorter*  to ask and expert in both languages (there are such) will give an answer with ease, but better answer you get from better `X` expert.